# React Router - passing location prop through function in Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Is there a way to pass the [location](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location) prop and own made prop to another component? I've figured out how to pass `DIR_URL` through a function like below but I also need to use `location` prop later in `ConfirmAccount` component to read `pathname` property and so on. (Of course in this way it gets `true` value).

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/structure/Main';
import ConfirmAccount from './components/pages/ConfirmAccount';
import NoMatch from './components/pages/NoMatch';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3006';
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/confirm">
              {/* How can I pass the location? */}
              <Route path="/:url" component={() => <ConfirmAccount DIR_URL={url} location />} />
            </Route>
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React Router DOM automatically passes `match` `location` and `history` props.

You can use the route render prop to pass them manually if you wish:

```
<Route path="/:url" render={(routeProps) => <ConfirmAccount DIR_URL={url} {...routeProps} />} />
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you use `useHistory` hook from ReactRouterDom inside your child component. There you got all the location stuff that you need.

Or pass route properties to rendering component:

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from './components/structure/Main';
import ConfirmAccount from './components/pages/ConfirmAccount';
import NoMatch from './components/pages/NoMatch';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3006';
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route path="/confirm">
              {/* How can I pass the location? */}
              <Route path="/:url" component={(routeProps) => <ConfirmAccount DIR_URL={url} {...routeProps} />} />
            </Route>
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const ConfirmAccount = ({location}) => {
  const history = useHistory()
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately I don't use Hooks. Can I somehow use `useHistory` without Hooks?

Comment: Thanks! It works. Unfortunately I've already accepted @Kyle Lambert answer but yours is also fine. :)

Comment: Sure, no problem. It's good that you got the solution. Rep is not that primar

Answer (score 0):

just `import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'` and use it like this:

```
const location = useLocation()
```

now you can access the `location` object.
read more about it here: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

or you can use `withRouter` HOC like this https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I use somehow `useLocation` without Hooks?

Comment: @nymphais you can use `withRouter Hoc` instead, here is how https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter